# cannot install delve (golang debugger): "cannot find package "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"

Tags: go, delve

When installing delve in OSX:

```
brew install go-delve/delve/delve
```

I get:

```
cannot find package "gopkg.in/yaml.v2" in any of:
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.4.2/libexec/src/gopkg.in/yaml.v2 (from $GOROOT)
    /private/tmp/delve20160602-37993-zqtryr/delve-0.11.0-    alpha/src/gopkg.in/yaml.v2 (from $GOPATH)
```

Therefore I install gopkg.in/yaml.v2 with:

```
go get gopkg.in/yaml.v2
```

Got no error. Then tried again, but problem persists.

I wonder if it has something to do with GOPATH, it is set in:

/Users/macbox/Desktop/golang

How can I see the installed packages?

Comment: what is the output of go get -v gopkg.in/yaml.v2

Comment: there is no output

Comment: Check the $GOPATH. delve apparently is looking in `alpha/src/gopkg.in/yaml.v2` not in `/Users/macbox/Desktop/golang`.

Comment: @mattes brew installs delve using a temporary GOPATH. Not sure what's missing without debugging the recipe though, since I installed it here just fine. Maybe wipe the install and just try again?

Comment: You could set `$GOPATH=/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.4.2/libexec` and then `go get gopkg.in/yaml.v2` and then try to brew reinstall delve. I wonder if more dependencies are missing.

Comment: @mattes: setting GOPATH to that value yields: warning: GOPATH set to GOROOT (/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.4.2/libexec) has no effect
package gopkg.in/yaml.v2: cannot download, $GOPATH must not be set to $GOROOT. For more details see: go help gopath